# How to make code that's functionally similar to enumerate without actually using enumerate?

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x, enumerate

I suppose to write a code that prints out the value of a number that occurs twice in the list given, but they don't allow us to use a built in function on python. How would I be able to write it without using enumerate?

```
def find_second_occurrence(xs,v):
    count = 0
    value = None
    for i, x in enumerate(xs):
        if v == x:
            count += 1
            if count == 2:
                return i
    if (count < 2):
        return value
```

Comment: Implement your own `enumerate` function and use it.

Comment: @RickTeachey I don't know where to start. I don't really understand the concept of enumerate that well

Comment: You would make a function just like the one you've made. The counter increments every time you go through the loop. It returns a list of two-tuples with the item number and the item.

Comment: Note that you are not returning the *value* of a duplicate number, but the second *index* of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enumerate(sequence)` is pretty much similar to a construct of the form:

```
for i in range(len(sequence)):
    # get sequence[i] and return i and sequence[i] for all i's
```

So, in your code, replacing `enumerate` altogether could be done by:

```
for i in range(len(xs)):
    x = xs[i]             
    if v == x:
        count += 1
        if count == 2:
            return i
```

Or, without assigning to an `x` name to temporarily hold the sequence item:

```
for i in range(len(xs)):           
    if v == xs[i]:
        count += 1
        if count == 2:
            return i
```

Creating a little `my_enumerate` function, is also rather simple:

```
def my_enumerate(sequence, start=0):
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        yield start+i, sequence[i]
```

`start` has also been defined as to match that as used in `enumerate` and gets a default value of `0`.

Rather than `yield`ing values (if this is mystifying to you), you can create a list (generator comprehensions are similar to `yield`ing) comprehension and return that instead:

```
def my_enumerate(sequence, start=0):
    return [(start+i, sequence[i]) for i in range(len(sequence))]
```

Comment: can you explain what xs[i] does?

Comment: @fip `xs` is your list, for example `xs = [5, 1, 2, 4]`. `xs[i]` will *index* that list and get the item that's at position `i`. So, for example, `xs[0]` will be `5`, `xs[1]` will be `1`, `xs[2]` is `2` and so on. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) for a Python tutorial on lists where this is explained :)

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your own enumerate function might be something like this:

```
def my_enumerate(a_list):
    result = []
    counter = 0
    for item in a_list:
        result.append((counter, item))
        counter += 1
    return result
```

Unlike the built-in `enumerate`, which is a generator that yields one item at a time, your function is returning a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to Pythons [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), where the following is proposed:

```py
def enumerate(sequence, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in sequence:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```